# While installing rake 0.8.7 for Rails on a new computer, I get "unable to convert "\xFC" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, character-encoding, rubygems, rake

What does this mean? Is my system set for UTF when it should be ASCII or something?

Answer (score 2):

This problem has been nagging me on one of my machines for the past year, and I only solved it just now. The machine in question is an old ASUS laptop running 32-bit Ubuntu 12.04, Ruby 1.9.3, and RVM.  I had the same problem running gem update, but only with rake 0.8.7

Sadly, I'm a bit of a newb at this stuff, so I can't quite work it all out, but I ran into two separate issues - inability to update rake beyond 0.8.7, and inability to get the documentation to process correctly.  The second problem is the more difficult to understand, but, as I understand it, it results from one particular version of rdoc relying on SourceIndex, which was deprecated in November, 2011.

Both problems are gem-related - character sets in the OS, to name one potential cause, don't seem to be an issue. As best as I can tell, my version of the problem was that my paths weren't correctly set to update the gem program.  I'd type "gem update --system" from the prompt and gem would tell me that it was up-to-date, but rake wouldn't update and the characters wouldn't be correctly installed in the documentation for rake, either.

In retrospect, what apparently happened was that the path was set up so that gem update would affect a different version of Ruby than the one I was using under RVM.  So, the key is to update the gems you're using by running the update program without having to rely on the path.

The solution has four parts.  The first is to uninstall rake.

The second is to update the gems (this also makes it possible to update rake).  Usually, this can be done by just typing gem update --system  Since I'm using RVM, I did this by going into ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin and ran update_rubygems.  I suspect that my system fell out of configuration between the path and multiple versions of Ruby.  By going directly to the ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin directory and running the update_rubygems command,the system was able to update both the correct rdoc gem so it correctly translated the characters, and the correct rake gem, both of which are gems in the rvm-managed version of Ruby.

The third stage is to reinstall rake.

The fourth is the usual suite of testing and hygiene commands - gem clean, gem update, gem list, etc.

I regret not having a better handle on this, but hope this helps.